# avconv - Passing list of image paths

Tags: ubuntu, libavcodec

I want to write a script that will generate a timelapse video based on a set input of image file paths. I understand that you can execute something like this:

```
avconv -r 15 -i %04d.JPG -s hd480 -vcodec libx264 time-lapse.mp4
```

That will look for files in a directory based on a file name pattern of 0000.JPG, 0001.JPG, etc. However, I am trying to figure out if there's a way I can pass it in a list of file names in the order I want processed?  My ideal situation is that I can perform some DB query to retrieve a list of image file paths in chronological order and then pass them into the avconv command and have it generate the video on the fly. I have a specific folder structure for my images so ideally I would not want to have to copy the necessary files into a temp directory in order to be able to name them properly and then process them.

Answer (score 1):

That's also the only way I got it to work (the image2pipe trick didn't work for me).

1. Make a folder with only the images you want in your movie.
2. Rename the files (make sure to backup your images before in case of error)

   ```
   aa=0;for i in `ls`; do mv $i `printf "%04d" $aa`.png; aa=$(($aa+1));done
   ```
3. Run  avconv

   ```
   avconv -f image2 -i %04d.png -b 2500k -codec mpeg4 Heligyro.avi
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up piping ls to create links and then rendering the links.

```
x=0; for i in $(ls -t *JPG); do counter=$(printf %05d $x); ln -s "$i" "$counter".jpg; x=$(($x+1)); done
```

Answer (score 0):

I do time lapse video based off images from my security camera. The camera sorts JPGs into folders by date and then into subfolders by hour.

This flattens, renames and pushes the result to avconv.

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_DIR="/home/ftp/camera/$1"
TIMELAPSE_DIR="/home/ftp/camera/timelapse-batch"
FRAME_DELAY=50

ls -1 $SOURCE_DIR |

        while read DAY;
        do
                echo "=================================================================";
                echo "| >>> Processing $SOURCE_DIR/$DAY";

                cd $SOURCE_DIR/$DAY;

                echo "| >>> Flattening...";

                find $SOURCE_DIR/$DAY -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -t $SOURCE_DIR/$DAY -i '{}' +

                echo "| >>> Frame Count: $(ls -1 | wc -l)";

                echo "| >>> Converting...";

                echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------";

                #gets list of images, renames them to a format that avconv expects, then runs avconv
                ls |
                        grep jpg |
                        awk -v name=$1 'BEGIN{a=0}{printf "mv %s " name "%04d.JPG\n" , $0, a++}' |
                        bash && avconv -y -r $FRAME_DELAY -i $1%4d.JPG -r $FRAME_DELAY -vcodec libx264 -q:v 4  -vf scale=iw:ih $TIMELAPSE_DIR/$DAY"_"$1.mp4;

                echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------";
                echo "| >>> Done!";
                echo "=================================================================";
                echo -e "\n\n\n\n";

        done
```